# Woocommerce Cart user based rest api

Tags: android, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I need the woocommerce cart rest api to add product in rt by andriod application

I have tried to create api but that will not help to me, from the same i have used cocart rest api plugin but that was also npt help to me

I have needed the woocommerce cart rest api behalf of user. like user based cart product rest api

Comment: Ok Have you try woocommerce native cart rest API?

Comment: Let me know then I will share you rest endpoint for the cart

Answer (score 1):

Install jwt auth plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/

Then After get jwt access token to validate user in cart

And pass the Bearer token in given end point

Woocommerce Add to cart rest endpoint:

```
    1. Add Item:

    curl --location --request POST 'https://example.com/wp-json/wc/store/cart/add-item' \
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer Y2tfZGQ5NGZkYWUwOGE2ODA5NDhhOGRiZDMxMTFkMmQ3OGU4YmYzNzRiNTpjc19hZjIzNTVhN2IzY2FmZTBiYWM1OWY1YWQxZjM2ZWFmM2VhOWMwZWU0' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --header 'Cookie: configurations=%20; woocommerce_cart_hash=e0913a1d62698d5a580e3dd51f499f89; woocommerce_items_in_cart=1; wp_woocommerce_session_84b205944f7fde9cce1f10026cbb5df6=1446%7C%7C1626429536%7C%7C1626425936%7C%7Ced554cee8fceb925791bd27c55680b23; PHPSESSID=37296a07f11acdf3a687b6f0482fc4d9; br_lgv_stat=default%7Cdefault' \
    --data-raw '{
        "id":"28694",
        "quantity":"1"
    }'

    OR

    curl --location --request POST 'https://example.com/wp-json/wc/store/cart/add-item' \
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer Y2tfZGQ5NGZkYWUwOGE2ODA5NDhhOGRiZDMxMTFkMmQ3OGU4YmYzNzRiNTpjc19hZjIzNTVhN2IzY2FmZTBiYWM1OWY1YWQxZjM2ZWFmM2VhOWMwZWU0' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --header 'Cookie: configurations=%20; woocommerce_cart_hash=e0913a1d62698d5a580e3dd51f499f89; woocommerce_items_in_cart=1; wp_woocommerce_session_84b205944f7fde9cce1f10026cbb5df6=1446%7C%7C1626429536%7C%7C1626425936%7C%7Ced554cee8fceb925791bd27c55680b23; PHPSESSID=37296a07f11acdf3a687b6f0482fc4d9; br_lgv_stat=default%7Cdefault' \
    --data-raw '{
        "id":"619",
        "quantity":"1",
        "variation": [
            {
            "attribute_pa_color" : "1",
            "attribute_pa_size" : "blue"
            }
        ]
    }'




    2. Remove Item:

    curl --location --request POST 'https://example.com/wp-json/wc/store/cart/remove-item?key=6483ce9734a7e0567b8c78a45b4726e0' \
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer bG9yZXMucXVpY2tmaXhAZ21haWwuY29tOkxvcmVzQDAwNw==' \
    --header 'Cookie: configurations=%20; woocommerce_cart_hash=e0913a1d62698d5a580e3dd51f499f89; woocommerce_items_in_cart=1; wp_woocommerce_session_84b205944f7fde9cce1f10026cbb5df6=1446%7C%7C1626429536%7C%7C1626425936%7C%7Ced554cee8fceb925791bd27c55680b23; PHPSESSID=37296a07f11acdf3a687b6f0482fc4d9; br_lgv_stat=default%7Cdefault'


    3. Update Item:

    curl --location --request POST 'https://example.com/wp-json/wc/store/cart/update-item' \
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer bG9yZXMucXVpY2tmaXhAZ21haWwuY29tOkxvcmVzQDAwNw==' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --header 'Cookie: configurations=%20; woocommerce_cart_hash=e0913a1d62698d5a580e3dd51f499f89; woocommerce_items_in_cart=1; wp_woocommerce_session_84b205944f7fde9cce1f10026cbb5df6=1446%7C%7C1626429536%7C%7C1626425936%7C%7Ced554cee8fceb925791bd27c55680b23; PHPSESSID=37296a07f11acdf3a687b6f0482fc4d9; br_lgv_stat=default%7Cdefault' \
    --data-raw '{
        "key":"6483ce9734a7e0567b8c78a45b4726e0",
        "quantity":"5"
    }'


    4. Add Coupon:

    curl --location --request POST 'https://example.com/wp-json/wc/store/cart/apply-coupon' \
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer bG9yZXMucXVpY2tmaXhAZ21haWwuY29tOkxvcmVzQDAwNw==' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --header 'Cookie: configurations=%20; woocommerce_cart_hash=e0913a1d62698d5a580e3dd51f499f89; woocommerce_items_in_cart=1; wp_woocommerce_session_84b205944f7fde9cce1f10026cbb5df6=1446%7C%7C1626429536%7C%7C1626425936%7C%7Ced554cee8fceb925791bd27c55680b23; PHPSESSID=37296a07f11acdf3a687b6f0482fc4d9; br_lgv_stat=default%7Cdefault' \
    --data-raw '{
        "code": "apptest"
    }'


    5. Remove Coupon:

    curl --location --request POST 'https://example.com/wp-json/wc/store/cart/remove-coupon' \
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer bG9yZXMucXVpY2tmaXhAZ21haWwuY29tOkxvcmVzQDAwNw==' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --header 'Cookie: configurations=%20; woocommerce_cart_hash=e0913a1d62698d5a580e3dd51f499f89; woocommerce_items_in_cart=1; wp_woocommerce_session_84b205944f7fde9cce1f10026cbb5df6=1446%7C%7C1626429536%7C%7C1626425936%7C%7Ced554cee8fceb925791bd27c55680b23; PHPSESSID=37296a07f11acdf3a687b6f0482fc4d9; br_lgv_stat=default%7Cdefault' \
    --data-raw '{
        "code": "apptest"
    }'


    6. Get All Items:

    curl --location --request GET 'https://example.com/wp-json/wc/store/cart/' \
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer bG9yZXMucXVpY2tmaXhAZ21haWwuY29tOkxvcmVzQDAwNw==' \
    --header 'Cookie: configurations=%20; woocommerce_cart_hash=e0913a1d62698d5a580e3dd51f499f89; woocommerce_items_in_cart=1; wp_woocommerce_session_84b205944f7fde9cce1f10026cbb5df6=1446%7C%7C1626429536%7C%7C1626425936%7C%7Ced554cee8fceb925791bd27c55680b23; PHPSESSID=37296a07f11acdf3a687b6f0482fc4d9; br_lgv_stat=default%7Cdefault'
```